# Angular - How do I join results of multiple api calls in one array using observable?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, observable, httprequest

I am using mongodb and express for backend and angular for frontend.

There are 4 api calls that need to be called:

1. /borrows
2. /books
3. /employees
4. /members

Each route has a collection in the database.

Borrows collection looks like this:

```
_id | bookID | memberID | employeeID | borrowDate | returnDate | deadlineDate
```

I'm trying to create an html table in angular that contains all the borrows populated with the names of the entities not their ids like:

```
_id                      | book     | member   | employee   | borrowDate | returnDate | deadlineDate
64160600a8263bfc45ad42db | 'Book 1' | 'John'   | 'David'    | 2023-03-18 | null       | 2023-03-20
```

I know how to do this with promises and I wouldn't have to go through the callback hell as I would be using async/await and I don't think that's possible with observables. How do I approach this problem?

I can't use subscribe() without entering the callback hell as I'm doing 4 api calls.

Comment: does this api calls depend on other api call ? like first you have to complete borrows then pick up some id or props from borrows then call books api something like that or just plane api call independendly ?

Comment: They are independent. I can call books, members, employees independently then do array manipulation to populate the borrows with the results that I got.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need 4 API call this can be done in only 1 api call.

Comment: I'm saving id references of book, member, employee inside the borrows table not the actual names of them I want to replicate the join functionality in relational databases by getting their names using their foreign keys given that this isn't a relational database this is mongodb.

Comment: You can also do this in mongodb as well. Learn populate and lookup in mongodb

Comment: Yes I can but I want to do this in the frontend in this case.

Comment: Check https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin :)